# Extjs 4 Can we have Grid with Combo always on i.e. without clicking on cell and in Editor show combo

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1.1

I want to show combo always in Grids perticular cell. 
i.e. not on click editor will get on and show combo.

When page get's load always show with Grid with one cell with combo.
earlier I have used, "itscomponentcolumn" for this, want to know is there any other solution for this ?

I will explain with the help of images..

on page load we get Grid something like this.

[image]

and after cell click we get Grid with that particular cell with combo.i.e.
[image]

So I want, without click on cell always show combo on each cell of the "Light" Grid's column.

i.e on page load structure of Grid should be like

[image]

I hope I am able to explain my requirement.

Please suggest the possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Is the problem that you are seeing the code value instead of the display value?  Or is this just a requirement?

Comment: I have edited my question with images, Hope that will explain my requirement. please suggest me what can be done here.

Comment: Can anybody suggest me and for this ?

Comment: This is actually very technical and hard to do.  If the problem is that people can't tell the cells are editable, you could always put a border around editable cells so they can tell.